# Why is linearity not satisfied for this inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The inner product given is $\langle u,v \rangle = u_{1}^{2}v_{1}^{2} + u_{2}^{2}v_{2}^{2}$. If I am thinking of linearity correctly, then all that means is the coefficients in front of each like term would be the same, so there wouldn't be something like $5u_{1}^{2}$ and $3u_{1}^{2}$. So why doesn't this inner product work?

Edit: In my notes, linearity is written as $\langle u,c_{1}v_{1} + c_{2}v_{2}\rangle$ = $c_{1}\langle u, v_{1} \rangle + c_{2}\langle u, v_{2} \rangle$. I still don't get it. Does linearity mean you can't have terms that are to the third power and above? If so, why?

Comment: You must have an exact definition of "linear."  What is it?

Comment: Try computing $\langle u,c_1v_1+c_2v_2\rangle$ explicitly for this candidate inner product and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things simple, try an example with $c_1=c_2=1$.

> $$\begin{eqnarray*}\langle u,v + w\rangle & = & u_{1}^{\,\,2}(v+w)_{1}^{\,\,2} + u_{2}^{\,\,2}(v+w)_{2}^{\,\,2}\\ & = & u_{1}^{\,\,2}(v_1+w_1)^{2} + u_{2}^{\,\,2}(v_2+w_2)^{2}\\\langle u, v \rangle + \langle u, w \rangle & = &  u_{1}^{\,\,2}v_{1}^{\,\,2} + u_{2}^{\,,2}v_{2}^{\,\,2} + u_{1}^{\,\,2}w_{1}^{\,\,2} + u_{2}^{\,\,2}w_{2}^{\,\,2}\\& = &  u_{1}^{\,\,2}\left(v_{1}^{\,\,2} + w_{1}^{\,\,2}\right)+ u_{2}^{\,\,2}\left(v_{2}^{\,\,2} + w_{2}^{\,\,2}\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$These aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you quote as written in your notes is the correct definition. It does indeed follow from that definition that

> you can't have terms that are to the third power and above.

You ask "why?". The answer is that with powers greater than $1$ the identity
$$
\langle u,c_{1}v_{1} + c_{2}v_{2}\rangle = 
c_{1}\langle u, v_{1} \rangle + c_{2}\langle u, v_{2} \rangle
$$
will fail. Try it with the example in your question.